# How to create DataFrame from Json data where two fields has same key but differ in caps?

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to create DataFrame from Json data where two fields has same key but differ in caps. For example,

```
{"abc1":"some-value", "ABC1":"some-other-value", "abc":"some-value"}

{"abc1":"some-value", "ABC1":"some-other-value", "abc":"some-value1"}
```

At present, I am getting following error,

```
  org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'ABC1' is ambiguous.
```

This is how I created DataFrame,

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json(inputPath)
```

I also tried creating RDD first where I read every line and changed the key name in Json string  and then converted RDD to Dataframe. This approach was very slow.

I tried multiple ways but still same problem remains.

1. I tried to rename the columns name but still error is there

   ```
   val modDf = df
    .withColumnRenamed("MCC", "MCC_CAP")
    .withColumnRenamed("MNC", "MNC_CAP")
    .withColumnRenamed("MCCMNC", "MCCMNC_CAP")
   ```
2. Created another DataFrame with renamed columns

   ```
   val cols = df.columns.map(line => if (line.startsWith("M"))line.concat("_cap") else line)
   val smallDf = df.toDF(cols: _*)
   ```
3. Dropping duplicate columns,

   ```
    val capCols = df.columns.filter(line => line.startsWith("M"))
    val smallDf = df.drop(capCols: _*)
   ```

Comment: can you share what you've tried?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I have added what I have tried so far.

Comment: how did you create the dataframe from json? where is that code?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan...please have a look. I have edited.

Comment: Please check the answer below :) I hope its helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read it as text rdd using `sparkContext` and then use `sqlContext` to read the `rdd` as `json`

```
sqlContext.read.json(sc.textFile("path to your json file"))
```

You should have your `dataframe` as

```
+----------------+-----------+----------+
|ABC1            |abc        |abc1      |
+----------------+-----------+----------+
|some-other-value|some-value |some-value|
|some-other-value|some-value1|some-value|
+----------------+-----------+----------+
```

The `dataframe` generated would have defect though as **duplicate column names are not allowed in spark dataframes (case insensitive)**

So I would **recommend to change the duplicate column names before you convert the jsons to dataframe**

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("path to your json file").map(jsonLine => jsonLine.replace("\"ABC1\":", "\"AAA\":"))
sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
```

now you should have `dataframe` as

```
+----------------+-----------+----------+
|AAA             |abc        |abc1      |
+----------------+-----------+----------+
|some-other-value|some-value |some-value|
|some-other-value|some-value1|some-value|
+----------------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Your first solution solved my problem. I was already doing line by line replacement but it was not giving optimum performance. Probably, I need to play with spark config. :) I have 20 nodes cluster(1 node = 16 GB RAM, 4 core) for 1 TB data. Can you suggest some config which can make it better.

Comment: I am not good on that. all I know is you have to partition data to distribute data in the cluster evenly and that you have to create executors tha a node can handle . not more and not less

Comment: Can you help in finding solution to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971566/how-to-handle-keys-in-son-with-special-characters-in-spark-parquet