# How to handle keys in Json with special characters in spark parquet?

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am trying to create data frame from json in parquet format. I am getting following exception,

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name "d?G?@4???[[l?~?N!^w1   ?X!8??ingSuccessful" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;

I know that some json key having special characters is a reason for above exception. However, I do not know how many keys have special characters.

Also, one possible solution is to replace special characters in keys with underscore or blank while creating RDD and reading line by line.

I am creating parquet file using following code,

```
  dataDf.coalesce(1)
  .write
  .partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "hour")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter", "\t)
  .format("parquet")
  .save("events")
```

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I have added the code for creating parquet. Please have a look.

Comment: can you also share the column names of your dataDf dataframe? All of them. If you cannot then check if there are special characters in the column names? if yes rename them before you write to parquet file.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I am processing ~10 TB of JSON data where JSON body is not uniform throughout. Also, number and name of keys are unknown to me.

Comment: when you have a dataframe called dataDf, I guess you can do dataDf.columns to get the column names in array. Just print them and see. If special characters are there then just replace them.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan renaming column before writing to file worked. Dhanyawaad !!

Comment: great to hear that :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Can you help me for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168960/how-to-read-multiple-directories-in-s3-in-spark-scala ? :)

Comment: Please go ahead. :)

Answer (score 0):

> > I know that some json key having special characters is a reason for above exception. However, I do not know how many keys have special characters.

If you don't know how many column names have special characters then you use `df.columns` to *get the column names and replace special characters in all of them*.

And **finally rename the columns before you write them to *parquet* files** should solve the issue you are having.

I hope the answer is helpful.