# How to read multiple directories in s3 in spark Scala?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have directories in s3 in following format,

```
 <base-directory>/users/users=20180303/hour=0/<parquet files>
 <base-directory>/users/users=20180303/hour=1/<parquet files>
 ....
 <base-directory>/users/users=20180302/hour=<0 to 23>/<parquet files>
 <base-directory>/users/users=20180301/hour=<0 to 23>/<parquet files>
 ....
 <base-directory>/users/users=20180228/hour=<0 to 23>/<parquet files>
```

Basically I have hourly subdirectories in daily directories.

Now I want to process parquet files the last 30 days.

I have tried following,

```
 val df = sqlContext.read.option("header", "true")
    .parquet(<base-directory> + File.separator + "users" + File.separator)
    .where(col("users").between(startDate, endDate))
```

where endDate and startDate are separated by 30 days and in yyyymmdd format.

Above solution is not giving correct subset of directories. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where` function is used in *filtering rows* in `dataframe`. And you are using it for read `parquet` files from *s3*. **So the whole concept is wrong**.

Instead you can *create an array of paths between startDate and endDate* and pass it to *sqlContext read api*.

**Programmatically speaking**, you can do something like below (they are just pseudo code)

```
val listBuffer = new ListBuffer[String]
for(date <- startDate to endDate)
  listBuffer.append(<base-directory> + File.separator + "users" + File.separator+"users="+date)

val df = sqlContext.read.option("header", "true").parquet(listBuffer: _*)
```

Comment: my pleasure @abhijeet thanks for the upvote and acceptance :)

Comment: ..is it possible to have a conversation with you over phone or chatting via IM...I am working on one tricky problem. Let me know.

Comment: You can ask a question on stackoverflow @abhijeet and not only me but everyone will help you

Comment: ..Ok. I request you to have a look at the following link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237513/handling-of-late-data-while-processing-data-for-last-n-days

Comment: I request you to have a look at following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49251699/aggregate-a-spark-dataframe-based-on-and-before-date

Comment: Please help in following issue. I have provided all the required information as well as the code which I have tried.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298263/spark-streaming-to-consume-json-data-from-kinesis-stream