# Aggregate a spark dataframe based on and before date

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with start_date column of date type. Now I have to generate metrics for unique values in column1 with start_date before or equal.
Following is a input DataFrame

```
column1   column2  start_date
id1       val1     2018-03-12
id1       val2     2018-03-12
id2       val3     2018-03-12 
id3       val4     2018-03-12
id4       val5     2018-03-11
id4       val6     2018-03-11
id5       val7     2018-03-11
id5       val8     2018-03-11 
id6       val9     2018-03-10
```

Now I have to convert into following,

```
start_date     count
2018-03-12    6
2018-03-11    3
2018-03-10    1
```

This is what I am doing which is not efficient way,

1. finding out all distinct start_dates and storing as a list
2. looping over list and generating output for each start_date
3. combining all outputs into one dataframe.

Is there a better way of doing it without looping ?

Comment: How do you get count 6 for `2018-03-12` ?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala 6 unique IDs(on and before 2018-03-12), similarly 3 unique IDs(on and before 2018-03-11).

Comment: @ShankarKoirala Please tell me sir which part is not clear. I will try to make it clear.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala In the table ...we need to focus on column1 and start_date. I am calculating all unique IDs which have entries on or before date 2018-03-12(which are ID1,ID2,...,ID6). Similarly for on 2018-03-11 or before, we have rows for 3 unique IDs(ID4, ID5 and ID6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine standard aggregation with window function, but the second stage won't be distributed

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._


df
 .groupBy($"start_date")
 .agg(approx_count_distinct($"column1").alias("count"))
 .withColumn(
   "cumulative_count", sum($"count").over(Window.orderBy($"start_date")))
```

Comment: Thank you. It fulfils the objective.

Answer (score 2):

Try Something like following -

```
groupBy("start_date").agg(countdistinct("column1"))
```

Explore in this pattern

Check countDistinct - [https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions](http://countDistinct%20Function)

use Spark Window - 
Example

```
val df = ... // schema => timestamp: TimestampType, stockId: StringType, price: DoubleType
df.groupBy(window($"time", "1 minute"), $"stockId")
  .agg(mean("price"))
```

Comment: I have tried groupby and agg + countDistinct but here I need to achieve cumulative calculations.

Comment: try something called window function