# Spark scala read multiple files from S3 using Seq(paths)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I have a scala program that reads json files into a DataFrame using DataFrameReader, using a file pattern like "s3n://bucket/filepath/*.json" to specify files. Now I need to read both ".json" and ".json.gz" (gzip) files into the dataframe.

Since current approach uses a wildcard, like this:

```
session.read().json("s3n://bucket/filepath/*.json")
```

I want to read both json and json-gzip files, but I have not found documentation for the wildcard pattern expression. I was tempted to compose a more complex wildcard, but the lack of wildcard documentation motivated me to consider another approach.

Reading the documentation for Spark, it says that the DataFrameReader has these relevant methods,

- json(path: String): DataFrame
- json(paths: String*): DataFrame

Which would produce code more like this:

```
// spark.isInstanceOf[SparkSession]
// val reader: DataFrameReader = spark.read
val df: DataFrame = spark.read.json(path: String)
// or
val df: DataFrame = spark.read.json(paths: String*)
```

I need to read json and json-gzip files, but I may need to read other filename formats. The second method (above) accepts a Scala Seq(uence), which means I could provide a Seq(uence), which I could later add other filename wildcards.

```
// session.isInstanceOf[SparkSession]
val s3json: String = "s3n://bucket/filepath/*.json"
val s3gzip: String = "s3n://bucket/filepath/*.json.gz"
val paths: Seq[String] = Seq(s3json, s3gzip)
val df: DataFrame = session.read().json(paths)
```

Please comment on this approach, and is this idionatic?

I have also seen examples of the last line with the splat operator ("_*") added to the paths sequence. Is that needed? Can you explain what the ": _*" part does?

```
val df: DataFrame = session.read().json(paths: _*)
```

Example of the splat operator use are here:

- [How to read multiple directories in s3 in spark Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168960/how-to-read-multiple-directories-in-s3-in-spark-scala)
- [How to pass a list of paths to spark.read.load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890344/how-to-pass-a-list-of-paths-to-spark-read-load)

Answer (score 3):

Adding further to blackbishop's answer, you can use `val df = spark.read.json(paths: _*)` for reading files from entirely independent buckets/folders.

```
    val paths = Seq("s3n://bucket1/filepath1/","s3n://bucket2/filepath/2")
    val df = spark.read.json(paths: _*)
```

The `_*` converts a `Seq` to variable arguments needed by `path` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use brace expansions in your path to include the 2 extensions:

```
val df = spark.read.json("s3n://bucket/filepath/{*.json,*.json.gz}")
```

If your bucket contains only `.json` and `.json.gz` files, you can actually read all the files:

```
val df = spark.read.json("s3n://bucket/filepath/")
```

Comment: What if you have multiple paths and want to pull from all of them, something like: `spark.read.json("s3n://bucket/filepath_a/", "s3n://bucket/filepath_b/", ...)`